# Sort by one field and remove elements by another, in a Map?

Tags: java, collections, dictionary, tree

Suppose there is `NavigableMap<Key, Value>` where `Key` would be:

```
class Key {
    private String keySort;
    private String keyRemove;

    //getters, setters etc.

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        //only include keyRemove
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        //only include keyRemove
    }
}
```

And there would also be a comparator:

```
class SortComparator implements Comparator<Key> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Key o1, Key o2) {
        return o1.getKeySort().compareTo(o2.getKeySort());
    }    
}
```

Now the map instantiation would look like this: `NavigableMap<Key, Value> myMap = new TreeMap<>(new SortComparator());` What I want is to have inside the Map, the **entries sorted only by the `keySort` and to remove them only based on `keyRemove`.**

The problem is that when I try to remove elements from the map, having only the `keyRemove` value, it does not work as expected (`NullPointerException` in Comparator). How can the above implementation be fixed in order to work with the expected behavior, or how can the expected behavior be implemented otherwise?

Edit: I understand what's wrong; the question remains still, for alternatives. From `TreeMap` JavaDoc:

> Note that the ordering maintained by a sorted map (whether or not an
>   explicit comparator is provided) must be consistent with equals if
>   this sorted map is to correctly implement the Map interface. (See
>   Comparable or Comparator for a precise definition of consistent with
>   equals.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am thinking that when you want to remove an entry in a map, the *remove* method will do the job based on the *equals* method: 
`(key==null ? k==null : key.equals(k))`
like described here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/AbstractMap.html#remove%28java.lang.Object%29.

One solution would be to implement your own remove method by iterating through all the keys in the *keyset* - searching for the removeKey, but that that will replace the O(1) complexity with O(n). Maybe this can be an workaround for you.